# How to translate "wall" as a verb?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, verbes

Phrases such as "wall in," "wall off," and "wall out" demonstrate the use of the word *wall* as a verb. I couldn't find a good translation for these phrases. I'm mostly wondering because I play a real-time strategy game that involves the use of defensive walls and players frequently say to each other "wall here" to mean "build a wall here," and I realized I wouldn't exactly know how that's said in French other than "faites un mur ici."

Comment: I can infer the meaning of "wall in" and "wall out", but what do you mean by "wall off"?

Comment: It means that something is blocked. If it's walled off, it means there is a physical barrier preventing entry. It's not very common I guess, but native speakers will understand it intuitively even if they haven't heard it before.

Answer (score 1):

Literal translation of "wall in" should be "emmurer", which literally means "put someone/something in between 4 walls"

However, usage for this word has often to do with a state of mind, like "s'emmurer dans le silence" -> "refuse to reveal any information even if it causes complications and can't help"

Correct way of saying "build a wall here" is "construisez un mur ici" or "édifiez un mur ici" (last one is more formal). But playing a STR, I and most of my friends would just say "wall là", franglish.

Answer (score 1):

The literal translation exists and is *[murer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/murer)*.

However, it is nowadays almost only used in specialized expressions like *murer la porte* or *murer la fenêtre*.

If you want a single verb, an alternative might be *[cloisonner](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/cloisonner)* (build a partition).